# Available memory on Raspberry Pi 2 (missing 240 MB)

Tags: memory

I just installed Raspbian (2015-01-31) on my brand new Raspberry Pi 2 with 1GB memory.

But I'm puzzled when I run `top` I only get: `KiB Mem: 762384 total`.

I've tried to set `gpu_mem=16` in config.txt but the result is the same.

Can anyone tell me why I cannot use the total of 1024 MB ram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do a `sudo rpi-update` that will probably give you back the missing memory.

The current arrangement is a temporary fix to allow sonic pi (and possibly unknown other software) to work properly.

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=685622#p685622

Comment: You were perfectly right. I was using the kernel with the sonic pi fix. After the rpi-update i had all my memory available. Thank you for your answer.